# Keyboard shortcut for opening http link in emacs or org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, keyboard-shortcuts, org-mode

When I am in org-mode and I have http links in my todo lists and my cursor is in the middle of a huge http link, is there a keyboard shortcut to copy that link so that I can paste it in a browser?

Take care,
Rajiv

Comment: Your question includes some misdirection. I assume that you don't want to browse the link,
since then `org-open-at-point` would have sufficed.
Therefore the remark about the browser is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry about the misdirection, but org-open-at-point is exactly what I wanted! I would love it if you could put that as an answer so that I can vote it up and give you credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I misunderstood you question at first, and I thought that you
wanted to e.g. embed the link into an email.

Then this code should have worked.

```
(defun myorg-copy-link ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-new
   (save-excursion
     (skip-chars-forward "^]\n\r")
     (when (org-in-regexp org-bracket-link-regexp 1)
       (setq link 
             (org-link-unescape 
              (org-match-string-no-properties 1))))))
```

But if you only want browsing, `org-open-at-point` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not in org mode, `browse-url' will open a url in your default browser.